# Dynamic rendering of a datagrid/table in React given JSON data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-virtualized, react-table

I have this json data that is gotten from an API end point.

```
        [{
            "id": 1,
            "style": "A",
            "color": "black",
            "size": "30",
            "quantity": "122.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "style": "B",
            "color": "maroon",
            "size": "24",
            "quantity": "48.00"
        },...]
```

I know I can use array.map() to loop over the data and give me a table with headers 'style','color','size', and 'quantity' with corresponding data rows below.

What I want to do is transform the rendering into this [table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRdEa.png) as it is more human-readable and a big plus would be to have the cells editable also (e.g. data ties back to state). Specifically, the sizes are in the column headers. How can I do this using either plain react/javascript logic or even better is there a popular React package that has this capability? Currently looking at react-table and react-virtualized but don't have enough experience on these packages to do something complex. Some code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: it is better to use react-datagrid

Comment: @Harikrishnan thanks for the suggestion. Some code example would be highly appreciated. I'm reading the docs but aside from creating a normal table, not sure how to transform the rendering as in the question.

Comment: i think there are enough examples available in [react-data-grid](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/) documentation,if you are stuck at implementing then put another question with the problem you face

Comment: As you are looking at react-table. this might be useful to you. 
https://react-table.js.org/#/story/editable-table

Comment: @GansPotter thanks for the link. Considering a 'Pivoting & Aggregation' table instead of the format in my picture. I'll just have to think of how to print things nicely. Would you happen to know if its possible to have pivot in the table and have the entries be editable at the same time?

Comment: I used react-table to do the same,it provides many features.Here is my project link where i used react-table and created an editable and complex table. https://github.com/AdnanShah/ReactJS-KretaHub-/blob/Thank_You_Init/src/app/routes/dashboard/routes/Default/rows.js

Comment: @Adnanshah thanks for the reference! I'll have a look at it tonight. Would be awesome if you could link a picture of how your table looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the image of the table which i created.Hope you are looking for this

[image]

And here is the link for the project

https://github.com/AdnanShah/ReactJS-KretaHub-